# Gitlab CI Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (22)

Tags: mysql, continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml

I am trying to connect to mysql in my CI workflow and to make sure setting up the DB worked I am passing in the echo command.

[image: YML file]

I get this error.
[image: Error on gitlab ci]

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this is'nt written as an Answer in every single question about this topic, and it is an absolutely retarded fix but here it goes.

Add to the script section.

script:

- sleep 300
- [do other scripts here]

The container is started but the db has'nt had time to be installed yet. Thats why it did not work.